# Identifying key meanings and transposing definitions in new column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data (random words) and have assigned each word to be a different word in another sheet in Excel (a key). I want to create a column next to the list of data (random words) that are defined in my other sheet. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking - perhaps you need to give some sample data.

Comment: Isn't that what VLOOKUP is for?  Or am I confused about what you are asking?  Maybe you could show us a small sample of what each sheet looks like?

Comment: Got it! Was using VLOOKUP but forgot to keep cell references contant